# Why does a `tcolorbox` code listing box using `listing above text` not keep the output with the code?

Tags: floats, tcolorbox, boxes, geometry, tcblisting

I'm trying to use a `tcolorbox` to list code above output in a document with 2 geometries. My attempt is failing utterly and I can't figure out why.

Here's the problem:

[image: problem tcolorbox]

The box is being split into two, with only the code part of it actually seeming to be inside the box. I put an `\fbox` around the text inside the `tcolorbox` to make it clearer that both it and the rules are supposed to be inside the lower half of the `tcolorbox`. Instead, this remainder ends up elsewhere and, because it ignores the instruction to grow left into the margin, it ends up off the page. Moreover, even in its own terms, it doesn't float properly: while it moves to the next page, leaving the code behind, the remainder of the current page is left empty, even if there is material after the box.

`\textwidth` inside the box reflects the growth into the margin, so the problem of going off the page is due to the displacement/failure to recognise that when actually placing the box. But, of course, even if it was placed correctly, it would still be separated from its other half.

How can I stop the box breaking into pieces and ensure both parts end up positioned correctly with respect to the instruction to grow into the margin? Why doesn't the `floatplacement` option cause the whole thing to just float to a whole-page-space?

```
\pdfminorversion=7
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,calc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,xparse}
\geometry{headheight=12pt,marginparwidth=45mm,hmarginratio=4:1,vscale=.8,hscale=.7,verbose}
\newlength\tewadjust
\setlength\tewadjust{\marginparwidth+\marginparsep-\paperwidth+\textwidth+\oddsidemargin+1in}
\newdimen\tdimen
\tdimen=\textwidth
\advance \tdimen by \tewadjust
\tcbset{%
  chronos ee/.style={
    float,
    floatplacement={!tbp},
  },
  cod chronos/.style={
    chronos ee=#1,
  },
  cod chronos dew/.style={
    cod chronos=#1,
    grow to left by=\tewadjust,
  },
  every float=\centering,
}
\NewTCBListing[auto counter]{codchronoshirbox}{ s O {} m }
{%
  IfBooleanTF={#1}{cod chronos dew=#3}{cod chronos=#3},
  listing above text,
  halign lower=center,
  #2,
}
% END preamble
\begin{document}
\kant[1-3]

\begin{codchronoshirbox}*[label=event-years-on-line]{Illustration of {event years on line}}
  \noindent\hrule width \textwidth height 30pt\medskip\par
  \noindent\hrule width \tdimen height 30pt\par
  
  \noindent\fbox{\parbox{.9\textwidth}{\kant[8-9]}}
\end{codchronoshirbox}  

\kant[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `listing above text`  creates two boxes and it looks as if only the first floats. You could make a feature request to change that. Or don't let tcolorbox handle the float but put it in a normal float, e.g. a figure.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. It also doesn't obey the width adjustment. For now, I've taken `tcolorbox` out of the picture completely. I tried what you suggested and putting it in a figure. That works fine, but it made `tcolorbox` seem redundant. Except now I don't get the listing and the output, but surely there's another way to do that?!

Comment: well you don't use tcolorbox mainly for the floating, but for the frame and the "show listing and output" feature, so it doesn't get redundant if you put everything in a figure.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I realised I didn't really want the frame if I put it in a figure. (I was using `tcolorbox` also to generate the cross-reference stuff and in lieu of a caption. I don't want a number and title which doesn't work as a reference.) Is it reasonable to use it just for the "show listing and output" feature? It seemed like overkill, but I don't currently have another way to do it.